# Contagem de colunas não confere com a contagem de valores na linha 1

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

Preciso orientação de como identificar o erro nessa mensagem recebida apos importar arquivo de texto:

> 1136 - Contagem de colunas não confere com a contagem de valores na linha 1

As colunas da tabela são 10 e os dados inseridos tambem 10. VEJA:

```
INSERT INTO `cgts` (`id`, `nome`, `cidade`, `estado`, `email`, `tipo`, `titulo`, `mensagem`, `data`, `ver`) VALUES
(NULL, 'Álvaro', 

'Bau', '', '222.32.232.223', 'Curioso', 'Cultura inutil:-`, `Turritopsis é biologicamente imortal. ', '2017-04-05', '1');
```

Answer (score 3):

Você tem uma coluna a mais na sua listagem de colunas do que na de valores. De acordo com a query que você postou, está com a seguinte relação de valores:

```
id -> NULL
nome -> 'Álvaro'
cidade -> 'Bau'
estado -> ''
email -> '222.32.232.223'
tipo -> 'Curioso'
titulo -> 'Cultura inutil:-`, `Turritopsis é biologicamente imortal. '
mensagem -> '2017-04-05'
ver -> '1'
```

Creio que você tem um erro no dado `titulo`. Provavelmente sua intenção foi colocar uma aspa após "Cultura inutil:-", que está faltando. Aí fica da seguinte maneira:

```
id -> NULL
nome -> 'Álvaro'
cidade -> 'Bau'
estado -> ''
email -> '222.32.232.223'
tipo -> 'Curioso'
titulo -> 'Cultura inutil:-`' 
mensagem -> '`Turritopsis é biologicamente imortal. '
data -> '2017-04-05'
ver -> '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Verificar se seu id está como AUTO_INCREMENT, depois remova o id do insert.

```
INSERT INTO `cgts` (`nome`, `cidade`, `estado`, `email`, `tipo`, `titulo`, `mensagem`, `data`, `ver`) VALUES ('Álvaro', 'Bau', '', '222.32.232.223', 'Curioso', 'Cultura inutil:', 'Turritopsis é biologicamente imortal. ', '2017-04-05', '1');
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Legal você querer ajudar, mas você usou o campo de resposta para fazer um comentário. Você poderá postar comentários quando tiver [um pouco mais de pontos de reputação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor utilize o campo de resposta somente para postar uma solução ao problema de que a pergunta trata.

Comment: Jessika, obrigado pela dica mas, após efetuar essas alterações por vc indicadas a resposta que obtive foi a mesma ---> Mensagens do MySQL : Documentação
#1136 - Contagem de colunas não confere com a contagem de valores na linha 1

Comment: Tem como você colocar aqui o sql que você utilizou para criar a tabela? Para ver se eu consigo te ajudar.

Comment: # Nome  Tipo Agrupamento (Collation) Atributos Nulo Predefinido 
1 idPrimária int(5)   Não None  AUTO_INCREMENT  
2 nome  varchar(50) latin1_swedish_ci  Não   
3 cidade  varchar(50) latin1_swedish_ci  Não   
4 estado  char(2)  latin1_swedish_ci  Não   
5 email  varchar(50) latin1_swedish_ci  Não   
6 tipo  varchar(8) latin1_swedish_ci  Não   
7 titulo  varchar(100) latin1_swedish_ci  Não  
8 mensagem text  latin1_swedish_ci  Não None  
9 data  date      Não 0000-00-00     
10 ver  char(1)  latin1_swedish_ci  Sim 1

Comment: Você colocou no insert 'id', mas pelo o que você me enviou a coluna chama 'idPrimária'.

Comment: Desculpe, é só ´id´, eu que fiz confusão.

Comment: Eu criei a tabela no mysql: 
**CREATE TABLE `cgts` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `nome` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , `cidade` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , `estado` CHAR(2) NOT NULL , `email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , `tipo` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL , `titulo` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , `mensagem` TEXT NOT NULL , `data` DATE NOT NULL , `ver` CHAR(1) NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;**   

e coloquei o insert que te mandei ali em cima e funcionou.

Comment: Vou conferir novamente. tks

Comment: Ok Jessika, problema resolvido. Grato.